# Flutter gSheets API: How to insert/append more than one row inside the sheet

Tags: android, flutter, append, rows

Using this https://pub.dev/packages/gsheets

I was able to insert a row but would like to add multiple rows at once. No idea why the google sheets is not filling up with multiple rows

**home.dart**

```
for (var i = 0; i < gsIndex; i++)
                       {
                      Map<String, dynamic> pStatus =
                      {
                        ParadeState.rank : usersList[i]['RANK'],
                        ParadeState.name : usersList[i]['NAME'],
                        ParadeState.morningState : dropdownAMValue,
                        ParadeState.afternoonState : dropdownPMValue,
                        ParadeState.date : formatted,
                      };
                      print(pStatus);

                      await UserSheetsApi.insert([pStatus]);
```

Console output:

[image]

**UserSheetsapi.dart**

```
static Future init() async {
    try {
      final spreadsheet = await _gSheets.spreadsheet(_spreadSheetID);
      _userSheet = await _getWorkSheet(spreadsheet, title: 'Sheet1');

      final firstRow = ParadeState.getPS();
      _userSheet!.values.insertRow(1, firstRow);

    } catch (e) {
      print('Init Error: $e');
    }
  }

  static Future<Worksheet> _getWorkSheet(
      Spreadsheet spreadsheet, {
      required String title,
  }) async {
    try {
      return await spreadsheet.addWorksheet(title);
    } catch (e) {
      return spreadsheet.worksheetByTitle(title)!;
    }

  }

   static insert(List<Map<String, dynamic>> rowList)
  {
    _userSheet!.values.map.appendRows(rowList);
  }
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party here, so hopefully you were able to get the answer to this one.

The code you have, you are sending the data to Google Sheets as a list and not a map.

You need to replace the [ ] with { }. Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gsIndex; i++) {
        Map<String, dynamic> pStatus =
            {
                ParadeState.rank : usersList[i]['RANK'],
                ParadeState.name : usersList[i]['NAME'],
                ParadeState.morningState : dropdownAMValue,
                ParadeState.afternoonState : dropdownPMValue,
                ParadeState.date : formatted,
            };
            print(pStatus);

            await UserSheetsApi.insert({pStatus});
}
```

The above also assumes that `gsIndex` is an integer. Use `gsIndex.length` if you need the number of items within a list.

Hope this helps.